# Fonction grammaticale concernant le verbe « s'agacer »

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, verbes, fonction-grammaticale

Dans la langue des médias on trouve de nombreuses constructions du type suivant.

> "En temps de guerre, ils sèment le chaos dans la gestion de la capitale", s'est-il encore agacé.
>
> ([Guerre en Ukraine : le torchon brûle entre Volodymyr Zelensky et le maire Vitali Klitschko, dans une bataille politique pour Kiev](https://www.msn.com/fr-fr/actualite/monde/guerre-en-ukraine-le-torchon-br%C3%BBle-entre-volodymyr-zelensky-et-le-maire-vitali-klitschko-dans-une-bataille-politique-pour-kiev/ar-AA1dbG6p?ocid=msedgdhp&pc=U531&cvid=fa1d8a89997c487fa86e97b233739815&ei=17))

« Agacer », en tant que verbe pronominal se construit avec la préposition « de » assez souvent, mais elle manque toujours dans cette construction.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/agacer)) B.− S'agacer de qqc. Éprouver une impression désagréable, un sentiment pénible, etc.

On peut conclure qu'il s'agit plus probablement de l'acceptation suivante.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/agacer)) A.− S'agacer. Se causer à soi-même une sensation désagréable

Le [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/agacer/1590) et le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/agacer) ne fournissent pas de sens qui permette une analyse grammaticale évidente.

Quelle est la relation grammaticale de « « En temps de guerre, ils sèment le chaos dans la gestion de la capitale » » avec le verbe ? S'agit-il d'une nouvelle [fonction grammaticale](https://www.alloprof.qc.ca/fr/eleves/bv/francais/les-fonctions-syntaxiques-f1243) ?

Answer (score 4):

Non, la personne ne s'agace pas elle même.

L'**incise**<sup>1</sup> indique qu'elle est agacée par ce qu'elle vient de dire et que son agacement se ressent dans sa manière de s'exprimer.

On retrouve le même modèle avec *se lamente untel*.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/incise) **Incise**: Proposition généralement de peu d'étendue et syntaxiquement indépendante, intercalée entre virgules dans le corps de la phrase ou rejetée à la fin de celle-ci, utilisée pour indiquer que l'on rapporte les paroles ou les pensées de quelqu'un ou pour introduire diverses nuances (supposition, opinion, explication, interrogation).</sub>

Comment: Tout ça est assez logique, et sans même chercher ce que signifie précisément « s'agacer » on a une idée de ce qui est exprimé, mais la question concerne la fonction grammaticale :  les grammairiens reconnaissent que tout constituant dans la phrase doit avoir une fonction (sujet, attribut, cod, etc.). C'est ce problème qu'il faut résoudre.

Comment: J'ai bien compris la question et y ait répondu, il s'agit d'une *incise*, clairement identifiable grâce à l'inversion.

Comment: Vous y avez répondu, oui, mais après que je vous ai fait remarquer que cela manquait. Il y a au moins maintenant une réponse qui correspond à la question ; cependant, je doute fort que ce soit la bonne : une incise est une proposition indépendante, et on peut donc l'éliminer (ce qui reste doit être correct).  « s'est-il encore agacé » n'a pas de sens sans la soit disante incise.

Comment: Non, j'avais indiqué avant ton commentaire qu'il s'agissait d'une incise et je pensais, à tort, que ça te suffirait à comprendre le rôle de cette proposition. Je ne comprends pas ta dernière objection, l'incise, c'est précisément « s'est-il encore agacé ». La proposition principale n'est pas une incise mais du discours direct, c'est simplement une citation.

Comment: C'est ce que je pensais, l'incise c'est bien « s'est-il encore agacé », mais il doit y avoir un complément manquant, parce que c'est une [incise de citation](https://www.linguistiquefrancaise.org/articles/cmlf/pdf/2008/01/cmlf08080.pdf) ; seulement il est impossible de placer un complément qui soit logique dans ce bout de phrase. Ce ne serait pas une incise correcte.

Comment: Il s'est agacé **du fait qu'ils sèment le chaos dans la gestion de la capitale**. Il n'y a rien d'illogique ou d'incorrect.

Comment: Le verbe n'est pas « s'agacer de » mais « s'agacer ». Ce n'est pas le même verbe ; le TLFi mentionne deux verbes distincts et « s'agacer » ne peut pas avoir de complément.

Comment: Ma réponse initiale mentionnait le verbe *se lamenter* qui est tout à fait équivalent : [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lamenter) *[En proposition incise] Dire en se lamentant. **« Il nous quittera » se lamentaient les uns : « Non, certes, le voici resté » applaudirent les autres** (Mallarmé, Dernière mode,1874, p. 785).*

Comment: Il n'y a qu'un verbe *s'agacer*. Il peut être utilisé de diverses façons.

Comment: **Les attaques personnelles sont inappropriées,** et seront supprimées. Merci de garder la conversation polie et civile.

Answer (score 2):

Je crois que c'est un complément d'objet unique du verbe transposé dans une [incise](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/53282) d'où l'absence de la préposition *de*. La personne s'agace [*de*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de) quelque chose, la chose qu'elle vient de dire ou plus exactement le sens de cette chose soit l'état de fait qu'« en temps de guerre, ils sèment le chaos dans la gestion de la capitale ». Ça rappelle aussi le cas où la préposition introduit le complément d'un verbe pronominal de sens passif, comme on peut modifier le verbe pour « être agacé par + (le fait qu') en temps de guerre... ». On peut faire une recherche de « pronom. » dans l'article « de » au TLFi.

Comment: Il s'agit soit d'aucun complément (« A » du TLFi), et ça n'a pas de sens, soit d'un COI (« B »), mais alors rien n'indique qu'il s'agit de « B » parce que le complément manque et que forcément « de » manque aussi. Je crois qu'il s'agit d'une tournure illogique.

Comment: @LPH Je la ressens comme très idiomatique et je perçois clairement _s'agacer de qqch_ avec l'incise et ce n'est certainement pas soi-même. Il ne s'agit pas de maths, comme tu sais. Tu ne peux faire dépendre la langue de la manière dont le TLFi décide de la présenter. Il s'agit de choix lexicographiques.

Comment: « Complément d'objet unique » n'est pas une fonction grammaticale ; je n'en ai même pas entendu parler une seule fois ; un complément d'objet est soit direct soit indirect. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=compl%C3%A9ment+d%27objet+unique